# How to convert a matrix to a triangular one without using numpy.tril() or numpy.triu()

Tags: python-3.x

I'd like to know how to convert a matrix to a triangular one without using the numpy built-in methods

Comment: Why don't you want to use the built-in methods?  What *exactly* are you trying to achieve, and why?  Can you just copy-paste the built-in methods' source code, since they obviously do what you need and are freely available?

Comment: I've been actually working on a Gaussian elimination problem where I was asked to create functions for exchanging rows, transvection...and I thought if there is a way to use these functions in order to get the wanted result or should I just go with the built-in methods?

Comment: Uh, just use the built-in methods.

Comment: Alright! I appreciate your help, can you please tell me, where can I find the source code for numpy.triu()?

Comment: Just click the `[source]` link on this page: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html